# How to open vim command output in separate tab/window?

Tags: vim, ruby-test

I'm using [vim-rubytest](https://github.com/janx/vim-rubytest) to execute tests from within MacVim.

This prints output in vim's command output window.
The problems are that this output is not scrollable or disappears after i switch to editor.

Is it possible to send this output to separate tab/window in Vim?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use vim-rubytest plugin but looking at the documentation it seems to me that by default vim-rubytest will put the contents into the quickfix list. To open the quickfix window issue the following command:

```
:copen
```

You can navigate the quickfix list via `:cnext` and `:cprevious`.

I belive the quickfix approach to be the preferred way, but to answer you question you can redirect the output into a register and then paste into a new buffer.

```
:redir @"
```

Then execute `<leader>T`. watch it all go by. Then end the redirection and create a new buffer with the contents inside.

```
:redir END
:new|pu|0d_
```

For more help see

```
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :redir
:h :new
:h :put
:h :delete
```

Comment: The output is not in quickfix!

Comment: @Sathish, are you sure? The README [claims](https://github.com/janx/vim-rubytest/blob/master/README#L24) that the plugin explicitly uses the quickfix window.

Comment: The default is to print output in terminal. In order to use quickfix the README suggests using `let g:rubytest_in_quickfix = 1`

Answer (score 0):

The default on `vim-rubytest` is for `let g:rubytest_in_quickfix = 0` this will execute everything on the terminal and echo the results.

In order to "open in a new window" you should set

`let g:rubytest_in_quickfix = 1` and then the output will be run and applied to the quickfix. This will open up a separate quickfix window that you can use see all the failures and allow you to jump to the file.

There is an issue with the usage of quickfix that I have filed on github ([Reference](https://github.com/janx/vim-rubytest/issues/24)) that doesn't allow you to open the first error. In the issue I posted a possible fix and have my own fork with it applied + some other minor adjustments to make using quickfix more ideal in my own TDD workflow.